# Explanation on Switch Statements

Tags: java

```
public class g{
    public static void main(String [] args){
    for(int x = 1; x <17; x +=3){
        switch(x){
            case -1: case 0: case 1:
                System.out.print("Breeze");
            case 2: System.out.print("Easy");
            case 3:
            case 4: System.out.print("As"); break;
            case 5: System.out.print("Pie"); break;
            case 6: case 7: System.out.print("No");
            case 8: System.out.print("Problem");
            case 9: break;
            case 10: System.out.print("Like");
            case 12: System.out.print("Nothing"); break;
            case 13:
            case 14: System.out.print("phew"); break;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Why is it that it prints out
BreezeEasyAs
As
NoProblem
LikeNothing
phew
I thought it would print the default after each one as in Breezephew for the first one

Comment: You could run execute your code in debug mode with appropriate breakpoints to know, what exactly is happening.

Comment: Just use a line by line debugger. Pretty self-explanatory then.

Comment: "print the default" You don't even have a `default` case.

Comment: I'm a beginner and I use geany so I don't know how to use a line by line debugger :|

Comment: have a nice username first :)

Answer (score 1):

It starts at `1` and it's going up in 3s (`x+=3`).

So you get `case 1` then `case 4`, `7`, `10`, `13`, `16`

**But** you don't always have `break`s so it falls through to the next `case` in some cases.

Which is why `case 1` actually gives "BreezeEasyAs", it runs `case 1,2,3 & 4` before it catches a `break`.

Answer (score 0):

for the first time when 
`x = 1` it prints `Breeze` 
but as there is no break in statement it keep on printing 
`Easy` & `As` so befor it reach the end System.out.println(); you will get `BreezeEasyAs` in the console and then it runs in similar way ( incremented every time by +3)

so the next time  :
`x = 4` it prints `As` find the break and again incremented by 3 
when 
`x = 7`  it prints `No` finds no `break` and prints `Problem` ( so the console output says `NoProblem`) hope you can figure out the rest

Answer (score 0):

Here are some points regarding switch-case structures you may benefit;

- switch-case is a special structure replacing if-else in some cases.
- In major programming languages (java, c++) only primitives,
  enumerators could be switched.
- case represents nothing but an anchor (or so called label) and for that reason only primitives are used since the jump label has to be known during compile-time.
- As case keywork actually represents a jump point, doesn't cause
  branching like if-else statements.
- Switch does the jumping part (just like **goto** used in some old
  programming languages)
- As it works by jumping the execution point, you have to put **break**
  keyword at the point you believe you are done with the **case**
- If you don't put break execution will continue.
- **default** keyword represents all of the case which are not handled, and is usually used for detecting unhandled cases

in your case consider that your are incrementing x by 3 and there is no **default**.  lets consider x = 7; in this case execution will jump to **case 7:** and continue execution until it reaches a break thus executes everything until **case 9** as there is the next break.